# iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ selection missing from Xcode 6.1 Interface Builder

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode6.1, iphone-6-plus

Im working on an application for iPhone 6+ with Xcode 6.1 and i can select the size for iPhone 6+ from the Interface Builder.

Yesterday my hard disk crashed, and i did a Time Machine restore. After that, my Xcode 6.1 does not support iPhone 6 and 6+ anymore, and all my simulator is missing. I tried to run my application on the iPhone 6+, all the screen is shrink to iPhone 5 size.

And all my simulator are missing.

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably a bug in the simulator.

We intentionally exclude the simulator data and logs from time machine backups, but I suspect there is a bug that is causing ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.default_created.plist to be backed up.  The existence of this file will prevent the sim from creating devices that it previously automatically created for you.

Assuming you have the file (please comment to confirm that my hunch is correct or if it is off base), delete it and then kill the simulator service and then check again:

```
rm ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.default_created.plist
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService 2> /dev/null
simctl list
```

Comment: its working, on xcode ver 6.3 (6d570) , i was not able to see  iPhone 6 simulator, but after running the code i started to see a long list of simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the iOS Simulator (by clicking on Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> iOS Simulator), then go to menu Hardware -> Device -> Manage Devices...
After that, in opened window under SIMULATORS you can press "+" button and add new simulators by choosing iOS Device Type.